# Getting error while reading excel sheet using python

Tags: python

```
from xlrd import *

book = open_workbook("File_1.xls")

#sheet = book.sheets()[0]           
#book.sheets() returns a list of sheet objects...     alternatively...
#sheet = book.sheet_by_name("qqqq") #we can pull by name
 sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)     #or by the index it has in excel's sheet collection

r = sheet.row(0)                    #returns all the CELLS of row 0,
c = sheet.col_values(0)             #returns all the VALUES of row 0,

for i in xrange(sheet.nrows):
print sheet.row_values(5)
```

I am reading a file which is in my desktop , but when I am running the script written in python it's giving error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\ReadXLS.py", line 6, in <module>
  book = open_workbook("File_1.xls")
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 449, in open_workbook
  ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
 File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 941, in biff2_8_load
 f = open(filename, open_mode)
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File_1.xls'
```

Comment: `book = open_workbook("File_1.xls")` Im assuming that `"File_1.xls"` is in the same dir as the script?

Comment: Are the file and the python script in the saem directory? Have you tried fully specifying the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `cd Desktop` before your run Python, as your error message says the file doesn't exist:

```
No such file or directory: 'File_1.xls'
```

Another fix would be to move the Python file into the same folder as the Excel file.

Comment: I have put the files in the same directory but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the script and file are in the directory, or specify the absolute path to your excel file.

Also note that if you try to open a file relatively, it will be done so using the current working directory where the python interpreter was initialized from.

I also recommend `openpyxl` http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/ if you ever need to work with the newer xlsx formats.

Comment: I believe openpyxl does not open xls files only the newer xlsx/m. Confirmed with the files i've just tried: 
  openpyxl.shared.exc.InvalidFileException: File is not a zip file

Answer (score 1):

**If ever, you are facing issue with paths, try finding your current path in the program**

```
>>> import os.path
>>> import os
>>> os.curdir
'.'
>>> os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
'/Users/xxxx/temp'
>>>
```

This is how it shows on Unix. It will show differently on Windows.

This way you will know, if that is the place where your current file is placed.

Code:

```
from xlrd import *
import os.path
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

book = open_workbook("File_1.xls")
#sheet = book.sheets()[0]           
#book.sheets() returns a list of sheet objects...     alternatively...
#sheet = book.sheet_by_name("qqqq") #we can pull by name
 sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)     #or by the index it has in excel's sheet collection

r = sheet.row(0)                    #returns all the CELLS of row 0,
c = sheet.col_values(0)             #returns all the VALUES of row 0,

for i in xrange(sheet.nrows):
print sheet.row_values(5)
```

Comment: @sarkar.shukla: Try debugging it this way.